# AngularJs clear form in Modal and set it ng-invalid

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, modal-dialog

i have a small problem with Angular JS and modal bootstrap.

This is the scenery:
I create a modal with bootstrap which contain a form. In this form i use angular validation with the built-in property `formname.$valid`.
When `formname.$valid` is false i set a submit-button to Hidden, when `formname.$valid` is true the same button is visible.

The problem is when i submit the first time the form closing the modal and clear all the input type. The second time i open the modal the property `formname.$valid` is true, instead it has to bee false.
Also the class of the form is set to `ng-valid`, however it has to be `ng-invalid`.
How can i resolve this problem?

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfLfvtrv/16/) demonstration which explains exactly my issue.

For the js fiddle project i reccomend you to use Chrome, because is the only browser i need to support (it's only a school project)

Thanks to all!

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

You need to visit documentation for ui-bootstrap

[Documentation ui-bootstrap](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

You include ui-bootstrap in your module and you don't use it for manage your modal

Look at this plunker for use `$modal`:

[Example modal angularjs](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)